# The function is printing gibberish into my file, even though the integer has the correct value

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILENAME "file.txt"
#define STRMAX 280

void read_from_file() {
    char temp;


    FILE*file = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        while ((temp = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
            printf("%c", temp);

        fclose(file);
    }

    else printf("0\n");
}

char counter_rows() {
    char temp, c;
    int i;

    FILE*file = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        while ((temp = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
            if (temp == '\n')
                i++;

        c = i + '0';
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return c;
}


void write_file(char c) {
    int i;
    FILE* file = fopen(FILENAME, "a");
    fputc(c, file);
    fclose(file);
}

int main(void) {
    char c;

    read_from_file();
    counter_rows();
    write_file(c);

    return 0;
}
```

The program is supposed to read the file, count how many rows there are in the file and add that number to the bottom of the text in the file.
When trying to run this program, I get the error

> 'c' is used uninitialized in this function"

and I can't seem to make it work.
I have tried printing the `int i` directly into the text file using `fwrite`, but that didn't work either.
I know that the integer i and the character c has the correct values because I added a debugging `printf` line.

Comment: Unrelated, `temp in `read_from_file` and `counter_rowws` should be `int` , not `char`. And you should seriously turn up your compiler warning levels; there are *plenty* to be concerned about, and *all* of them should be treated as outright errors (because that's what they are).

Answer (score 3):

Even after fixing the error with `c` with `c = counter_rows()`, when building the
executable without debug, you may have problems :

```
int i;
```

`i` is not initialized to any value so incrementing it is meaningless.

Fix by replacing with

```
int i = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing `c` in your `main()`, as the error message says. You need to save the result of `counter_rows()` with `c = counter_rows();`

Answer (score 2):

`c` in `main()` is different from `c` in `counter_rows()`. As the message says, you are using `c` (in `main()`) without initializing that.

You are returning `c` from `counter_rows()`, so you should have `main()` catch the value.

```
int main(void) {
    char c;

    read_from_file();
    // counter_rows();
    c = counter_rows(); // assign what is returned
    write_file(c);

    return 0;
}
```